# ReactJS: How to use boolean values in radio buttons?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, radio-button

What is the proper way to use boolean data in radio buttons. The values will be converted from booleans to strings if used directly.

JSON-data for input fields that is preloaded:

```
var question = [
  {value: true, name: "Yes"},
  {value: false, name: "Not this time"}
]
```

The radio button fields:

```
<input type="radio" 
       name="question" 
       onChange={this.state.onRadioChange} 
       value={this.state.question[0].value} /> {this.state.question[0].name}
<input type="radio" 
       name="question" 
       onChange={this.state.onRadioChange} 
       value={this.state.question[1].value} /> {this.state.question[1].name}
```

The binding for onRadioChange:

```
onRadioChange: function(e) {
    console.log(e.target.value);
}
```

The console log displays that the selected values are converted from booleans to strings.

One way to handle this would be add an extra function to the `onRadioChange` function to convert `"true"/"false"` strings to booleans from `e.target.value` but its feels a bit hackery. Also, using just 'e.target.checked' won't work, because in some radio button groups I have other values than booleans (that needs to be passed through).

Some universal and clean solution would be to use constant values table that is transformed from and to REST.

Are there any special ReactJS way to do it? Maybe not.

Comment: The value of an _Attribute_ is always a _String_. If this value must be _truthy_ or _falsy_ then the only _falsy String_ is `""`, i.e. `!""; // true`

Comment: @PaulS. Yes, good point. With JSON-data this is quite common situation that you need to bind boolean values to radio buttons and some frameworks/libraries have automatic conversions on bindings. I want to know how people does this with react and are there some magic helpers.

Comment: I think you can `foo || ''`, but you may need to check your submission data after as the false selection may disappear

Comment: Does this `value` mean the radio button is checked? Why do you want to set the radio button value to a boolean?

Comment: @dreyescat I want to keep the data structure similar to the original preloaded JSON

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Currently the solution is to convert the passed attributes from string values to boolean before saving.

```
var str2bool = (value) => {
   if (value && typeof value === "string") {
        if (value.toLowerCase() === "true") return true;
        if (value.toLowerCase() === "false") return false;
   }
   return value;
}
```

And calling the conversion:

```
onRadioChange: function(e) {
    console.log(str2bool(e.target.value));
    // Here we can send the data to further processing (Action/Store/Rest)
}
```

This way the data is ready to be send through actions to Rest or Stores and it works directly with the radio buttons.

Answer (score 10):

Use the checked attribute of input for radio buttons. That attribute uses  booleans.

Comment: e.target.value is still string which is different type than in the original JSON (they might use same data structure in Store)

Comment: event.target.checked

Comment: Checked is probably the right way to when dealing with booleans. Although, (in this case) sometimes I need to have string values with several buttons.

Comment: This does not work: target.checked will always be true

Answer (score 2):

In case that you are looking for a way to manage the radio button checked state with React, here you have an example:

```
var RadioButtons = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function () {
    // Assuming there is always one option set to true.
    return {
      question: this.props.options.filter(function (option) {
        return option.value;
      })[0].name
    };
  },
  onRadioChange: function (e) {
    this.setState({
      question: e.target.value
    });
  },
  render: function () {
    var options = this.props.options.map(function (option, key) {
      return (
        <li key={key}>
          <input type="radio" 
             name="question" 
             onChange={this.onRadioChange} 
             checked={this.state.question === option.name}
             value={option.name} /> {option.name}
        </li>
      );
    }, this);
    return (
      <ul style={{listStyle: 'none'}}>
        {options}
      </ul>
    );
  }
});
```

This component can then be used passing your `question` list as properties:

```
<RadioButtons options={question} />
```

Check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jnxzq0m3/2/).

Answer (score 2):

The best solution to handle yes/no is a checkbox because you can use a boolean with the help of target.checked.
If you want to use 2 radios instead unfortunately the simplest solution is to rely on strings.

You cannot use target.checked with radios (proposed in one of the answers) because it will always be true. If you click on the first radio, its target.checked inside handleChange() will be true, then if you click on the second radio its target.checked will also be true (e.g you'll never get false).

```
function handleChange(e) {
  const value = e.target.value;
  setState({answer: value});
}

<input
  type="radio"
  name="answer"
  onChange={handleChange}
  value="yes"
  checked={answer === "yes"}
/> Yes

<input
  type="radio"
  name="answer"
  onChange={handleChange}
  value="no"
  checked={answer === "no"}
/> Not this time
```

Full example: https://codesandbox.io/s/stack-overflow-34547733-nc04l

Answer (score 0):

When working with binary (true or false valued) radio buttons in in React use a truthy and a falsy string for each input value and then in your handleChange function use either: `Boolean(ev.target.value)` or `!!ev.target.value`. This will convert whatever string you have in `ev.target.value` into boolean.

Example:

```
       <input
        type="radio"
        name="radioButtonField"  
        value="foo"    //a truthy string 
        onChange={(ev) =>
          setState((currentState) => ({
            ...currentState,
            [ev.target.name]: Boolean(ev.target.value),
          }))
        }
      />
      <input
        type="radio"
        name="radioButtonField"
        value=""       //a falsy string
        onChange={(ev) =>
          setState((currentState) => ({
            ...currentState,
            [ev.target.name]: Boolean(ev.target.value),
          }))
        }
      />
```